# Postgresql install fail on Windows 8 pro 64

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to install PostgreSQL 9.2.4 on Windows 8 Pro 64, but nearly the end of the installation problem I am keep getting this error

"Problem running prop-install step. Installation may not complete correctly The database cluster installation failed."

I tried to install it few times, with firewall turned off, I also deleted 'postgres' user that is created for PostgreSQL. But I am keep getting this message.

I also tried with older versions. 9.1, 9.0 but I am keep getting the same problems.

Any one with similar problem ?

Comment: Any reason why you're keeping the relevant parts of the installation log a secret?

Comment: Also, as this doesn't seem to be a programming question specifically, it might be better asked elsewhere, such as dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Where did you put the data directory? That should not go into `Program Files`  (which is a restricted directory)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found solution here:

[PostgreSQL: "The database cluster initialisation failed"](http://forums.holdemmanager.com/general-support/150771-solved-postgresql-database-cluster-initialisation-failed.html)

You have to create user postgres and add him to the administrators. If you have "postgres" user created from previous failed postgres installations, delete it.
Run compmgmt.msc, create the user add him to the administrators by

> right click>properties>MemberOf tab>Add, write "Adiministrators" and Ok.

Than run cmd as the new postres user:

> runas /user:postgres cmd.exe

Run the postgres installation from this command prompt.

That worked for me.

Comment: "*You have to create user postgres*" that is no longer necessary with 9.x

Answer (score 0):

Or, simply just install in a new path (different from previous installations).

Though an explicit user 'postgres' is not created in Windows, still there seems to some zombie reference with this user 'postgres' having ownership level access to the folders that were created in previous postgresql installations.. You can hunt down the registry and clean it up if you are forced to use the same installation path.